# How to fix issue with apt and sources.list.d to install Yandex browser?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, browser, software-sources

I followed the instructions at [this page](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-yandex-browser-ubuntu-2/) to install Yandex browser.

When I did `apt-get update`, I got this error:

```
root@aspire:~# apt-get update
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

So apparently the [instructions](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-yandex-browser-ubuntu-2/) were not quite correct, because I entered the lines into `yandex-browser.list` as instructed

```
root@aspire:~# more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list
deb [arch=amd64]
http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb beta main
```

**So, if the problem is the first line, how should I change this?** I am guessing I need to remove the `[arch=amd64]` part, but then will I still get to the right package, as there are both a 32-bit and a 64-bit packate at the repository?

Answer (score 1):

All right, I just found the answer is that the two lines in yandex-browser.list should be one line: `deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb beta main` . That's all.

(I have very little experience editing these things by hand, usually use a PPA, so I wasn't aware it was that simple.)

I'll leave this question up, however, in case some other beginners are confused by the directions given at [that website](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-yandex-browser-ubuntu-2/) and encounter the same error.